# Inequality with choose function: $1\sqrt{\binom n1} + 2\sqrt{\binom n2}+3\sqrt{\binom n3}+\cdots+n\sqrt{\binom nn} < \sqrt{{2^{n-1}}{n^3}}$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, contest-math, radicals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

From the 1987 Spanish Mathematical Olympiad: Prove, for all natural numbers $n$ with $n > 1$, that $1\sqrt{n\choose1} + 2\sqrt{n\choose2}+3\sqrt{n\choose3}+\cdots+n\sqrt{n\choose{n}} < \sqrt{{2^{n-1}}{n^3}}$.

I tried using some estimates on the size of $n\choose k$, like ${n \choose k} \leq \frac{n^k}{k!}$, but nothing seemed to work, mainly due to all the choose functions being enclosed within square-roots.

Comment: @Martin R I think my solution is much more better than in your link. What do you think?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I does not matter which one I find better. The question is a duplicate, it has been asked and answered before. You should use your powers to close it as such. If you have a better solution then add it to the *other* question, so that all answers to the problem are at one place.

Comment: @Martin R If I'll use that I can not help to solve this problem. What do you'll say?

Comment: It is the other way around: It helps most if all solutions (including your new one) at at one place, and other identical question are closed as a duplicate.

Comment: May I remind you that this was discussed before, e.g. here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/discussion-with-michael-rozenberg-on-closing-duplicates: *"closing as duplicates does not delete anything. ...
It **helps to centralize solutions at one place.** And also to save the effort of users (so that they do not answer the same question again and again)."*

Comment: @Martin R I know this point, but I know also that there are users that closes these duplicates and deletes them with new and nice solutions. I don't agree with this thing. So I will try not to give to close this topic.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg (1) Closing a question as a duplicate does not mark the question for deletion. (2) I think that the answer provided to the old question is far superior to the one here---it uses more or less the same argument (i.e. an application of Cauchy-Schwartz), but obtains a *tighter* bound.  I don't see what is particularly "new and nice" about the answer here. (3) If you really think that your solution is so nice that it merits preservation against the possibility that someone will care enough to eventually delete this question, why not copy your solution to that question?

Comment: We can close this topic after  merging with the linked topic.   In the meantime, I open it.

Answer (score 1):

By C-S
$$1\sqrt{n\choose1} + 2\sqrt{n\choose2}+3\sqrt{n\choose3}+\cdots+n\sqrt{n\choose{n}}\leq\sqrt{(1^2+2^2+...+n^2)(2^n-1)} \leq\sqrt{{2^{n-1}}{n^3}}$$